# Unable to resolve Google Cloud DNS Managed Private Zone from Compute

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

I am using a Google Cloud DNS Managed Private Zone, which is unable to be resolved by Compute instances that are within the network permitted by the zone. I am using two Ubuntu 18.04 LTS standard images. The two instances are on two different subnetworks of the same network, which has been permitted to see the Private zone.

I am using GCloud CLI, and I am signed in and verified through gcloud init with a project selected that I am the Owner for.

I have tried adjusting /etc/resolv.conf to point to the metadata server specifically, however this simply stopped resolution altogether. I was originally using A records in the private zone which didn't work; based on this article https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-private-dns-zones/ I tried using CNAME for the [INSTANCE_NAME].[ZONE].c.[PROJECT].internal domain which also didn't work.

The setup I am doing is through GCloud CLI and is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

# gcloud init or gcloud auth activate-service-account must have been previously run

CUSTOMER=test
NETWORK=testnetwork

# configure Cloud DNS - create customer.workshop.local

gcloud dns managed-zones create "${CUSTOMER}internal" \
--dns-name="${CUSTOMER}.workshop.local" --description="A zone" \
--visibility=private --networks="$NETWORK"

# IP is derived through a gcloud compute call but presume it is:
IP=10.10.0.4

gcloud dns record-sets transaction start --zone="${CUSTOMER}internal"
gcloud dns record-sets transaction add "$IP" \
  --name="server.${CUSTOMER}.workshop.local." \
  --ttl=300 \
  --type=A \
  --zone="${CUSTOMER}internal"

gcloud dns record-sets transaction execute --zone="${CUSTOMER}internal"
```

When pinging from my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS machine in a subnetwork 10.10.1.0/24, I get:

```
david.alexander@jump-ubuntu-01:~$ ping server.test.workshop.local
ping: server.test.workshop.local: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Has anyone got any ideas? Cheers!

Comment: I do not see the command in your script to make the private zone visible to the network $NETWORK. `gcloud dns managed-zones update private --networks $NETWORK`. Do not modify /etc/resolv.conf. Google overwrites this file on a regular basis (DHCP lease expiration or about every 60 minutes).

Comment: Note: `[INSTANCE_NAME].[ZONE].c.[PROJECT].internal` is an example and not the actual name. the `.c.` part will be different (a, b, c ....). Get the hostname from this instance `hostname -f`.

Comment: Thanks John. I thought the last two options of the creation command set the network visibility? `gcloud dns managed-zones create "${CUSTOMER}internal" \
--dns-name="${CUSTOMER}.workshop.local" --description="A zone" \
--visibility=private --networks="$NETWORK"`

Comment: On the second point - I create my VM with `hostname=server.test.workshop.local`, but `hostname -f` just returns `server`, rather than the FQDN.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance so far!

Comment: The command line options for `hostname` vary among OS versions, etc. Look up what option returns the long hostname for your OS. Usually `man hostname` will do the trick if you have the help packages installed.

Comment: Creating a private zone is not the same thing as making it visible (active) in a VPC.

Comment: I'm getting `ERROR: (gcloud.dns.managed-zones.update) HTTPError 403: Forbidden` when I run `gcloud dns managed-zones update testinternal --networks testnetwork` - gcloud init says I'm still the Project Owner though.

Comment: Just because you are a "Project Owner" does not mean you have permission to all actions. Project Owner does have access to all resources. It does mean that you can grant yourself permission by adding a role to your IAM member account. Add the role `Service Networking/Service Networking Admin`. There are other roles that you can also use: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/job-functions/networking

Answer (score 1):

This has turned out to be an issue only with Ubuntu 18.04. Windows doesn't replicate this issue. *Edit* - CentOS has also been tested and not replicated this issue.

When I created a Windows server in this network and tried name resolution, it worked fine. The Canonical image for Ubuntu 18.04 (i.e. not a custom image) has name resolution to 127.0.0.53 through Netplan by default, and it can't query the Google Metadata server. Dig shows this on a default image - if you specify the metadata server, you are able to resolve the name.

I will log a bug with Canonical about this. Thanks John Hanley, I can't upvote you because you commented rather than answered - if you can ping me about how to do this I can do it.

Cheers!

Comment: However, I can upvote your answer. Thank you for posting details on the problem and the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try to do it following the official guide from Google Public documentation:

[Creating a private zone through GCloud CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dns/managed-zones/create)

[Creating a private zone through GUI](https://cloud.google.com/dns/zones/#creating_private_zones)

Just, I am seeing you missed the project:

```
gcloud dns --project=test record-sets transaction start --zone=testinternal
gcloud dns --project=test record-sets transaction add 10.10.0.4 --name=test.workshop.local. --ttl=300 --type=A --zone=testinternal
gcloud dns --project=test record-sets transaction execute --zone=testinternal
```

Comment: Thanks Agustin. Yes, I followed the documentation to the letter; and you don't need to specify a project when you use gcloud init/gcloud auth activate-service-account and have already specified a project context :)